# Exception: null when setting up Selenium using ThreadLocal and ChromeDriver (Version 75)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, thread-local

Current setup stored inside my DriverFactory:

```
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
return webDriver.get();
```

Currently the following method seems to be failing:

```
public void loadUrl(String url) {
    try {
        getDriver().get(url);
        System.out.println("Successfully navigated to URL: " + url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        Assert.fail("Unable to navigate to URL: " + url + ", Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Set driver method:

```
 public final void setDriver(String browser) throws Exception {
        String remoteHubUrl = "http://xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub/";
         try {
            switch (setBrowserType(browser)) {
                 case "grid":
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities =new DesiredCapabilities();
                    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                    ChromeOptions op = new ChromeOptions();
                    op.merge(capabilities);
                    webDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteHubUrl), op));
                        break;
                }
}
```

Exception Message:

```
Exception: null
```

There seems to be no issues when using older versions of chromedriver, any ideas?

Base Step which is used to initialise the driver prior to executing the tests:

```
@Before
public void setupHook()  {
    setDriver("grid");
}
```

Comment: What does `getDriver()` do?  When is `setDriver(<browser>)` called?  Are you passing the value "grid" into setDriver?

Comment: Here is a working implementation that may be a useful reference:  https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Comment: hey @Ardesco just updated my question, its very odd not sure why the logic works with older version of webdriver.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace rather than just `Exception: null`?

Comment: @Ardesco  it seems null is the only exception, even when attempting to print the stack trace.

Comment: I'm hoping to see the entire Stack Trace, not just the exception :)

Answer (score 0):

The main Issue I see with the above code is that you are trying to instantiate a RemoteWebDriver instance using a ChromeOptions object instead of a DesiredCapabilities object.

RemoteWebDriver requires a DesiredCapabilities (See [Selenium code here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#L117)) which ChromeOptions does not extend or implement.  They do both extend AbstractCapabilities so you may just have been getting lucky in the past, but now they have diverged to an extent that they are no longer compatible.

***EDIT***

I would suggest you update your code to do this:

```
switch (setBrowserType(browser)) {
    case "grid":
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        webDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteHubUrl),capabilities));
        break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for looking, even when running the tests locally using the options etc the same problem persists.